# Can H4 dependents travel first time to the US on previous employer visa stamping?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I got my H1B transferred to a new employer recently. My family is in India with H4 visa stamped with previous employer but never travelled to the US. Now, if they want to travel to the US, do they require to get the stamping done once again in India with new employer documentation? Or can they travel with previous stamping it self?